# Assesing individual bits in an int in mips?

Tags: mips, bit

I'm new to mips. I know the basic functions (How to use registers, printing and scanning ints using syscall) but I've hit a wall when trying to figure out how to access the individual bits of a 32-bit integer to count the amount of 1s that are in it. I was thinking that I perhaps had to create an array of ints to represent all of the bits? But I feel like there must be an easier way.

Comment: Please provide what and how you have tried..

Comment: What you want is the _popcount_, and you can start reading about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

Comment: I might be missing something but this popcount of yours doesn't solve the question of "how accessing individual bits in an int in MIPS"... why was this even upvoted??

Answer (score 0):

basically:

```
int countOnes(int number)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 32) {
        count += number & 1;
        number >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: the user clearly said MIPS... this answer is useless

Comment: There's no mention of the endianness and MIPS can do both? https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Endianness